# How to debug R fatal error when accessing mdb-database via ODBC

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

I get this messages when i run the code below.

*R Session Aborted.
R encountered a fatal error.
The session was terminated.
Start new session.*

Message appears after 5-10 seconds. I have 64 bit ODBC driver for MS Access version 16.00.16501.2009 (ACEODBC.dll). I use Microsoft 365 64 bit (Office). I have Windows 11 Home. I run RStudio 2023.06.0 Build 421. I have R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt) -- "Already Tomorrow". Everything is updated today including the R packages. I can connect to the database file and get records from a table (e.g. 14000 records from table station in code below) in the database if I hurry, but after ca 5-10 seconds I get the "R encountered a fatal error" as described above. I cannot disconnect during these seconds. The weird thing is that I have managed to get it to work correctly once with the same configuration. The code has been running for years without problems on my old computer (32 bit R, Office etc).

If I run the same script in the R console (RGui) the whole RGui will crash and disappear. My codesnippet for testing is simply this:

```
library(RODBC)
mdbConnect<-odbcConnectAccess2007("file.mdb")
sql<-"SELECT * from station"
u<-sqlQuery(mdbConnect, sql)
odbcCloseAll()
```

I have tested to use packages DBI and ODBC directly without RODBC but the exact same error occurs.

Any ideas on how to fix the problem or how to debug to find out where the problem lies is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem disappeared after installing windows update KB5027303 July 3 2023.